# InputStream doesn't retain UserDefinedFileAttributeView attributes

Tags: java

I want user to download a new  template file everytime he logs in so I am thinking about setting a user defined attribute for the file which it will keep in session and show an error message if he tries to upload that file in any later session.

For user defined attribute, I am taking timestamp. But it looses the attributes once I convert the file to inputstream, for the user to download.

EDIT: I expect the file which user will get and then upload back in the same session to retain the timestamp I stored in the custom attribute "user.timestamp". But the file which reaches user has no custom attribute whatsoever.

```
        File templateFile = new File(context.getRealPath("resources") + "/downloads/template.xlsx");
        Path filePath = Paths.get(templateFile.getAbsolutePath());

        UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files
                .getFileAttributeView(filePath, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);

        view.write("user.timestamp",
                    Charset.defaultCharset().encode(timestamp.toString()));



        InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(templateFile);
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Template.xlsx");
        IOUtils.copy(fileStream, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but "it looses the attribute...". Could you please edit your question and add description: 1. what you expect to happen, 2. what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact *copying the **content*** of your template file to the servlet response. Exactly as the [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) says:

> Copies bytes from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`.

Your code works so you are *not* copying the *file*, just its *content*.

In fact in the servlet response you are not sending a *file*, you are sending a stream of bytes which are then interpreted by your browser as an Excel file. The `Content-Disposition` is just a trick for your browser, read e.g. this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260519

> When Internet Explorer receives the header, it raises a File Download dialog box whose file name box is automatically populated with the file name that is specified in the header.

The file on your disk is then created "from scratch" *by your browser*.

The idea of "simply transferring a file *as is*" is contradictory - the file meta-data have different format and structure based on each operating system.

By the way, what you are doing is not thread-safe. You are setting the *global* file properties for a single user - what if another user creates another session in the meantime?

You can either use cookies for storing this information in the user's browser, then each consequent request will send you the cookie as a part of each consequent request, or you should solve on the level of business logic, which is out of scope of this question :) For this formulate a completely new question, based not on technology, but on your use case. Something like: "I need to achieve this, I have already tried this and it did not work, is there a pattern/algorithm for it?"

Comment: Yes, I suspected as such. Do we have an alternative then? I need to ensure that what user uploads is the same file, he downloaded in the same session?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this ?